# HELP w-2 and 1099 during a divorce

Tags: irs, form-1099, form-w-2, divorce

In the middle of a divorce were we owned a company contracted with another to provide management and advisory.
I was also employed as an employee for same company we contracted with.  We split last year and I was fired by my husband, I feel out of retaliation because he knew the divorce was going to come.  Financially disabling me.  Now I got my W-2 and 1099 and both seem inaccurate to what I was actually paid.  What to I do? Husband was also, withholdings funds during this time accepting money paid on the contract and keeping me away from knowing what was actually going on. He had opened a second bank account with a friend that I did not kow about for months.  Was told by my husband that if I set step on the property I would be arrested for trespassing...

Comment: Please talk to a lawyer. Our advice can only go so far.

Comment: When you say the tax documents “seem inaccurate,” do you mean that you don’t really know, or do you mean that the tax documents do not match your records?

Comment: don't match my records

Comment: Adding pleas for help to your title won't get you answers any faster. Also, you might want to consider not rolling back edits to the post unless they actually make substantive changes that are incorrect.

Comment: Please understand that it's impossible to help you without a substantial knowledge here, of many things pertaining to you and/or your marriage. You'll get the wrong answers online, so don't make that mistake and contact a lawyer.